# Order by null first, then order by other variable

Tags: mysql

this is my code for now:

```
SELECT id, number
FROM Media
WHERE user = 10
ORDER BY id, number
```

but I want it to look like:

```
SELECT id, number
FROM Media
WHERE user = 10
ORDER BY while(number IS NULL), id
```

What I want to do is to have all `number` that are `NULL` on the top of the result, but as soon `number` is not `NULL`, sort by `id`

Is that possible?

I use mysql.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

what about something like this :

```
SELECT id, number
FROM Media
WHERE user = 10
ORDER BY (case when number is null then 0 else 1 end), id
```

If number is NULL, the first order by criteria will be 0 ; else 1

Which means every line will number NULL will come before the others ones

And note that ids will be sorted too, anyway.

You'll get something like this :

- number null ; id=1
- number null ; id=2
- number null ; id=5
- number null ; id=8
- number not null ; id=3
- number not null ; id=4
- number not null ; id=7
- number not null ; id=10
- number not null ; id=12

Comment: That is how I normally do it as well.

Comment: Excellent! Fast answer, and it worked first time I tried. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The ISNULL() function returns 1 if the parameter is null and 0 otherwise.

```
SELECT id, number
FROM Media
WHERE user = 10
ORDER BY ISNULL(number) DESC, id
```

Mind you, terrible for performance depending on how many values it needs to order: no index will be used based on the ORDER BY columns.

Answer (score -1):

Union could be used as well.

```
SELECT id, number
FROM Media
WHERE user = 10 AND number IS NULL
ORDER BY id

UNION

SELECT id, number
FROM Media
WHERE user = 10 AND number IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY id, number;
```

Comment: Apart from a slightly wrong syntax (missing parentheses), this won't make sense because the `UNION` will not guarantee preservation of the ordering of individual selects. Besides, this produces an unnecessarily expensive execution plan (two `NULL` checks on the `number` column).