# I Have to sort the list with a field by taking only the not null values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sorting

How to sort the list with a field which has both null and not null values with the not null values.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Over Flow..When you ask a question, Please state your problem clearly with examples, and what you have tried... etc

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347894/order-by-null-first-then-order-by-other-variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
ORDER BY
     CASE WHEN <COL> IS null THEN 1 else 0 END
```

This will order rows with NOT NULL COL values first followed BY rows with NULL COL values